Quartz cannot trigger job then the application is stop
I got this error
24.08.01 03:19:30 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:19:55 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:20:23 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:20:46 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:21:11 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:21:35 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:21:59 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:22:29 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:22:56 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:23:22 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:23:50 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:24:17 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:24:41 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:25:07 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:25:32 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:25:55 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:26:20 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:26:45 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:27:13 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:27:38 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:28:06 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:28:31 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:28:58 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:29:22 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:29:47 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:30:14 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:30:41 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:31:06 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:31:31 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:31:55 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:32:21 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:32:51 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:33:15 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:33:43 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:34:09 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:34:35 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:35:01 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:35:30 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:35:53 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:36:18 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:36:44 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:37:13 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:37:40 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:38:10 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:38:35 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
24.08.01 03:39:02 DEBUG [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] [org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers

I have class:
 SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory();
    scheduler = schedFact.getScheduler();

JobDetail action = newJob(action.class).withIdentity("action",
          "Test").storeDurably().requestRecovery().build();

Trigger imAllTrigger = newTrigger()
          .withIdentity("ActionTrigger")
          .forJob(action)
          .withSchedule(
              simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(60)
                  .repeatForever())
          .startNow()
          .build();

scheduler.scheduleJob(action, imAllTrigger)

The app runs with java8. After run for a while, the app cannot trigger the new job and n the application crashes and stops.
I couldn't reproduce this error in my local test instance.
Do you have any idea about this?
I use quartz version 2.3.2
Thank you in advance,
